# Notice: Undefined index: field4 error en la ejecución de la consulta

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un problema con un cuestionario web

me esta marcando el siguiente error al insertar las repuestas en la base de datos

error en la ejecución de la consulta.

Notice: Undefined index: field4 in \ruta..... error en la ejecución de la consulta.

este es mi encuesta

```html
<?php
$id = 4;
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','webtopy');
$sql = "SELECT id, texto FROM respuestas WHERE id = '".$id."' Order by id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
echo "<form action='reciborespuestas.php' method='POST'  NAME='form'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<fieldset>
                  <legend>".$row[1]."</legend>
                  <label> 
                      <input type='radio' name='radio".$row[0]."' value='1'> Si
                  </label> 
                  <label> 
                      <input type='radio' name='radio".$row[0]."' value='0'> No
                  </label> 
                <td>
                    <input type='submit' class='submit' value='Ver' />
                </td>
            </fieldset>";
}
echo "</form>";
?>
```

y este es donde inserto en la base de datos

```html
<?php
$id = 4;
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','webtopy');
$sql = "SELECT id FROM respuestas WHERE id = '".$id."' Order by id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
 
 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $id_preg= $row[0];
        $resp= $_POST ['field'.$id_preg];
 
        $consulta="insert into opciones ('valor', 'idenc') values ('$resp','$id_preg')";
        $resultado=mysqli_query($conn,$consulta);
 
                if ($resultado) {
                        echo "perfil almacenado. <br />";
                }
                else {
                        echo "error en la ejecución de la consulta. <br />";
                }
}
?>
```

Comment: Si tú envías por ejemplo la respuesta de este input: `<input type='radio' name='radio".$row[0]."' value='1'>`, cuando vas a recuperar con POST o con GET u otro, debes hacer referencia  al `name` del elemento. En el elemento el `name` es **`radio`**  más el valor numérico que haya en la variable obtenida de `$row`. Por lo tanto el POST debería ser **`$_POST ["radio$id_preg"];`**. De todos modos, cuando recuperas algo con POST o con GET es bueno usar `isset`, porque puede que no siempre el dato se esté enviando. `isset` te permitirá verificar si ese dato se envió o no y actuar en consecuencia.

Comment: ya estoy apunto de conseguir lo que quiero solo que tengo una ultima consulta, como puedo separar ya en mi $resp me guarda toda la información que quiero solo que no se como separar el numero 26 y el numero "1" de cada respuesta me manda una cadena así array(6) { ["radio26"]=> string(1) "1" ["radio27"]=> string(1) "1" ["radio28"]=> string(1) "1" ["radio29"]=> string(1) "1" ["radio30"]=> string(1) "0" ["id"]=> string(2) "18"

Comment: ya esta solo que no guarda en la BD

Comment: Lo que muestras es un array, y puedes acceder a los valores que hay dentro de él sea leyéndolo dentro de un bucle, o si quieres acceder a un determinado valor acceder por su índice, por ejemplo `echo $resp["radio26"];` te imprimirá el número `1`, y si quieres el `id`, lo mismo, accedes a él por `$resp["id"]` te dará el valor `18`...

Comment: muchas gracias ya esta solucionado